# How can i unnest a string field into rows in SQL BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

how to unnest a string field
Table Flags : id of type integer and categories of type string

| ID | Categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1201 | Uncategorized, Issues from Project Side, CI Configurations Issue |
| 1202 | Machine Stability, Machine Stability, Machine Stability, |

Output needed

| ID | categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1201 | Uncategorized |
| 1201 | Issues from project side |
| 1201 | CI Configurations Issue |
| 1202 | Machine Stability |
| 1202 | Machine Stability |
| 1202 | Machine Stability |

Thanks

```
 select *,
  (select ( categories)
    from unnest(split(categories)) categories
 )as  distinct_product_count
   

 FROM `Flags`
```

i got  error Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery to do this, you are right to use `split` within the `unnest` function but you can specify it right after the `from` clause like this:

```sql
select 
  ID,
  category
from `Flags`, unnest(split(categories)) as category
```